# Is it possible to have a ListPlot with a FrameLabel but no ticks?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to format a plot so that there are no ticks or scale on either axis, but there is a label on each axis. I think AxisLabels are hard to read and would prefer to have the labels where FrameLabel puts them, but I can't remove the ticks without removing the frame (and as far as I can tell, you can't have a FrameLabel without a Frame). Here's my code.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, Ticks -> None, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Cumulative adopters"}]
```

Is there any way to do this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `FrameTicks` if you specified `Frame -> True`

```
ListPlot[
 Range@10,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 FrameTicks -> None,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Cumulative adopters"}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
ListPlot[
 Range@10,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 Ticks -> None,
 Frame -> False,
 AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Cumulative adopters"}]
```

[image]

The most important differences are

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Supplementing eldo's answer, you can specify which frame lines are shown:

> For [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), and related functions, `Frame->{{left,right},{bottom,top}}` specifies whether to draw a frame on each edge. With the default setting `FrameTicks->Automatic`, ticks are included whenever a frame is drawn.

```
ListPlot[
 Array[Sinc, 10, {0, 3 Pi}],
 Axes -> False,
 FrameTicks -> None,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Cumulative adopters"}
]
```

[image]